# Using JSF2 library versioning. Why am I keeping old versions around?

Tags: jsf-2

I started with docroot/resources/myname/1_0_1/css, js and images. When I need to update a file, I copy 1_0_1 into 1_0_2 and make my change(s) there. And so forth.

Am I being too literal in my understanding of the correct procedure?

Wouldn't it be sufficient just to rename 1_0_1 to 1_0_2, etc. so I don't end up with a long chain of old versions? I have source control if I need to refer back, of course.

Comment: What exactly stops you from renaming?

Comment: Nothing. It's just that every example I saw had a list of successive versions. So I thought that's how we had to do it. But I don't have to do it that way? As long as I up the version number, I'm good. Right?